# Numpy module not found, but I have installed numpy

Tags: python, numpy, installation

I am using Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. I am trying to install some software (python-fsps) using `sudo SPS_HOME=$SPS_HOME python3 setup.py install`. However, this gives me the error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`. I really should have numpy installed, becasue I can use it in sessions on Anaconda. Also, running `pip3 install numpy`, tells me `Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/lzucker1/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.18.5)`. I have also tried`conda install -c anaconda numpy`, but it does not recognize conda, which is also weird becasue I do have conda on my computer. I have tried defining `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/anaconda3/bin` in my ~/.bashrc file, but that does not change anything. I would greatly appreciate any advice.

Comment: You installed NumPy for yourself, but you're trying to install that other thing as root.

Comment: Are you sure you installed numpy into the right python editer?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica what other thing are you referring to?

Comment: @AnnZen What do you mean by the right python editor?

Comment: For example, you have `spyder` and `pycharm` installed, and you only install `numpy` into `spyder`, but you try to import it in `pycharm`.

Comment: @user1093541: python-fsps

Comment: So a module can be installed but only in one application? How do I fix that?

Comment: How can I install numpy as root so that I can access it when trying to install python-fsps?